# How to add more than one parameters in ChicagoBoss route

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I am trying to get the following link to work:
http://localhost:8001/name/jason/grey

and the routes definition:

```
{"/name/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)", [{controller, "stuff"}, {action, "getStudentNames"}, [{firstname, '$1'}, {lastname, '$2'}]]}.
```

and then in my controller

```
getStudentNames('GET', [FirstName, LastName])->
  {output, "ok"}.
```

I get the following error message

```
CRASH REPORT Process <0.313.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching boss_router_controller:'-index_and_extract_params/1-fun-0-'([{firstname,'$1'},{lastname,'$2'}], []) line 258 in gen_server:terminate/7 line 812
```

Seems I am not getting it right with the routes definition, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, should in case there is anyone with the same issue. Instead of using list of tuples in the route definitions to define the parameters, use tuples separated by commas e.g

```
{"/name/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)", [{controller, "stuff"}, {action, "getStudentNames"}, {firstname, '$1'}, {lastname, '$2'}]}.
```